# PHP: replace newlines in array without loop

Tags: php

I need to replace all newlines in this array

```
$fields = [ "hello", "new\nold", "world"];
```

by a `|` without a loop.

I tried with `array_walk()` but failed.

Using PHP 7.4

Comment: Try [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: What do you mean by a new line? Do you mean this "\" ?

Comment: @GazmendSahiti https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: No matter what solution you use, it still uses one or more loops. They are not explicit `for(;;)` or `foreach()` loops but they are still there, in the functions `array_map()`, `array_walk()`, `str_replace()` with an array as it third argument etc. These hidden loops are faster than an explicit loop though, that's why we prefer to use them when possible instead of explicit loops in the PHP code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest and fastest solution is as easy as:

```php
str_replace("\n", '|', $fields);
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/v3Tip).

Read the documentation of [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

---

N.B. The code above does not contain any explicit loop. However, a loop exists in the implementation of `str_replace()`. An operation on all items of a list cannot be done without using at least one loop.

The difference between an explicit loop in the PHP code and a loop hidden in a built-in PHP function is in the speed of the code execution. The code of `str_replace()` is written in C (a language that produces fast executable code) and it is already compiled as executable code for the hardware where it runs. A loop in PHP code needs to be parsed and compiled into bytecode, then the bytecode is interpreted by the PHP interpreter. The code of any built-in PHP function is much faster than the PHP code.

Comment: This is simply easy. Upvoting this.

Comment: https://php.net/str_replace: "If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well".

Answer (score 4):

use array_map:

```
$fields = ["hello", "new\nold", "world"];

$replaced = array_map(function ($item) {
    return str_replace("\n", '|', $item);
}, $fields);
```